# sam build --use-container --debug not working

Tags: docker, sam

sam build --use-container is not working, just exit without any logs. I tried with debug still same issue.

$ docker --version
Docker version 20.10.8, build 3967b7d
$ sam --version
SAM CLI, version 1.38.0

$ sam build --use-container --debug

no logs after running this command.

is there any way to get more logs, or know the actual issue?

Answer (score 0):

It seems these was some bugs with sam-cli version 1.38.0. Once I updated to 1.38.1 it's works as expected.